# How can I retrieve a list of websocket connections?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm working on a chatbot project where we open a websocket connection to communicate the chat messages.

Sometimes we get duplicate messages back and forth. I suspect that a second client is booted. I want to modify the boot() function so that it checks for existing websocket connections (and either cancel booting or close all other connections first).

Is there a way to get this from a vanilla javascript perspective? or do I maybe need to do something from the backend?

Comment: To get a handle of all the websocket connections on the client side you can push them into a global array of websockets in your clients' memory as soon as you open them and at some arbitrary point check how many WebSocket instances were pushed into the global array. From the backend perspective it would depend on the language and framework you're using.

Comment: I'm using express and nodejs, but I think what you mentioned about pushing the instances into some kind of array is probably the best method.

Comment: Another option would be to make a wrapper around the WebSocket object; like a function `currentWebsocket` that would open a WS connection the first time you run it, then save it to a variable and return it on subsequent calls

Answer (score 1):

I tried to figure it out by looking at the code but without even a line number on which the error appears, it's pretty hard, anyways.

I suppose this is the problem here:

```
conn.send('USER_CONNECTED:' + conn.id); // send the connect message to ONE user
conn.broadcast('USER_DISCONNECTED:' + conn.id); // send the disconnect to ALL users
```

So it seems that you're simply missing a broadcast call when a user connects.